# Create a view from 2 tables without repetitions

Tags: sql, sql-server

SO bear with me
I want to create a view that combines data from 2 tables:

RETRY:

```
TaskId  status
   1       13
   2       4
```

Files

```
FileId(key) TaskId  Study
  1          1       2.3
  2          1       2.3
  3          2       4.5
  4          2       4.5
```

I need a joined view:

```
TaskId   Study
 1         2.3
 2         4.5
```

what I get is:

```
TaskId   Study
 1         2.3
 1         2.3
 2         4.5
 2         4.5
```

since task id always belongs to the same study,  I need to get only 1 study for each task Id.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TASK_TO_STUDY] As (
SELECT dbo.RETRY.task_id 
FROM    dbo.RETRY_TASKS dbo.FILES.Study
LEFT JOIN   dbo.FILES ON dbo.FILES.task_id = dbo.RETRY.task_id  
);
```

Comment: What does `Study` represent? Will it always be the same value for a given `TaskId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work based on the input data and expected data according to your explanation

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TASK_TO_STUDY] As (
SELECT DISTINCT r.task_id,f.Study 
FROM    dbo.RETRY_TASKS r 
JOIN dbo.FILES f ON f.task_id = r.task_id  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the task. Then you can use an aggregate function (like `min`) to take a specific study

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TASK_TO_STUDY] As 
(
  SELECT dbo.RETRY.task_id, MIN(dbo.FILES.Study) as Study
  FROM    dbo.RETRY_TASKS 
  LEFT JOIN   dbo.FILES ON dbo.FILES.task_id = dbo.RETRY.task_id
  GROUP BY dbo.RETRY.task_id 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword to retrieve only the distinct unique combinations of the selected columns:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TASK_TO_STUDY] As 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT dbo.RETRY.task_id, dbo.FILES.Study 
 FROM    dbo.RETRY_TASKS dbo.FILES.Study
 LEFT JOIN   dbo.FILES ON dbo.FILES.task_id = dbo.RETRY.task_id  
);
```

This assumes that `Study` will always have same value for a particular `Task_id`. If that is not so, and what you actually want is the sum of all values of `Study` for a `Task_id`, you can go with Juergen D's answer.